# Include two https requests in Node js via the same html button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I have an HTML button that sends a POST request and would like to do some kind of verification before making the request here.
The verification involves a GET request, where I make sure that a certain table contains a certain value or not. After that, if the condition is valid I make the POST request else I use the value I fetched from the GET request.
Even though this sounds basic I'm not sure how to do this in Nodejs.
Here is how code is organized now,
Her is the HTML button:

```
<form action="/generate_survey" method="POST" id="gen_survey">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-3">Get Survey Link</button>
</form>
```

And I have a router.js that includes all the routes:

`route.get('/generate_survey', controller.test)`

then here in the controller.js, I have the db and other call functions.
So here is the test function where I want to make the request

```
exports.test = (req, res)=>{
.....

}
```

Should I put the GET request results in a variable and then depending on that I make the POST request?
If so I'd like to see an example of how to something similar in Nodejs
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you do everything in one call? Make your verifications in Node, and if everything is good, launch your second Node instruction on the fly (call the database or whatever). There's no need to send back the validation result to the browser, then call the server a second time with a POST request.

Comment: ok so what you saying is to include all the logic in one function, right?

Comment: Exactly. Well, it can (and should) be a chain of small functions, like `validate()` then `saveToDatabase()`, but all in one go, server-side. Besides, if you validate something server-side, then send it back to the browser, you open a security breach. What you send back to the browser can be modified and 
 tampered with, between the first and the second call. If you leave everything server-side, it's more secure (and simpler, and faster).

Comment: Makes perfect sense and I had this idea initially but for some reason thought it was not the right approach. I'll try it out, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Angular we can do this way. so hope same applies to Nodejs as well. adding form method just for ref. you can check the actual one.

form onsubmit="do_something()"

```
do_something(): boolean{
   // do get operation here
   return true; // submit the form

   return false; // don't submit the form
}
```

Comment: doSomething() return true or return false? What does it have to do with anything? And why Angular? :) What is this code supposed to do or teach?

Comment: I have added form tag, it's not displaying in code. Usually when we click on submit we call this dosomething(). If it returns true form will submit further that means 'action' if it returns false it won't submit the form. Using angular code bcoz I am just showing the logic not exact code.